# ArgumentException when doing eager loading in EF7

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to load a model with several navigation properties. Most of the referenced models load fine, but when trying to `Include()` a referenced List the project crashes with `System.ArgumentException - Static field requires null instance, non-static field requires non-null instance`.

Loading

```
var project =
    db
    .Projects
    .Include(x => x.Fittings) // offending Include
    .Include(x => x.CostParameter) // works
    .Include(x => x.ProcessParameter) // works
    .Include(x => x.CreatedByUser) // works
    .Single(x => x.Id == package.IsPartOfProjectId);
```

To make matters a bit more complex the List in question is of an abstract class. Furthermore, the list can also contain subclasses of another abstract class.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ButtWrap>().HasBaseType<Fitting>();
modelBuilder.Entity<Elbow>().HasBaseType<ButtWrap>();
```

The model configuration

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Project>()
    .HasMany(x => x.Fittings)
    .WithOne(x => x.Project)
    .IsRequired()
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
```

Project Model

```
public sealed class Project : CommonTypes.ProjectBase
{
    public int ProjectTrackingNumber { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsManufacture { get; set; }
    public bool IsCostEstimate { get; set; }  
    public string QueueStatus { get; set; }    
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }

    public List<Fitting> Fittings { get; set; } = new List<Fitting>();
    public Meta Meta { get; set; }
    public FittingsInterfaceUser CreatedByUser { get; set; }

    public CostParameter CostParameter { get; set; }
    public ProcessParameter ProcessParameter { get; set; }
}

public class ProjectBase : EntityBaseIdentifier, IAggregateRoot
{
    public ProjectBase(long entityId) : base(entityId)
    {

    }

    protected override void Validate()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

The somewhat complex structure aside, I actually had this working earlier. However somewhere down the road I've introduced an error.

Since the error is somewhat cryptic I don't really know where to start looking, so all suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Please show the `Projects` class.

Comment: @CodeCaster Edited in.

Comment: @VolodymyrBilyachat For now it's just a POCO with the Id of a project that exists in the Database.

Comment: Try making your `Fittings` property as `virtual`.

Comment: @KGChristensen Try `virtual ICollection<Fitting>`. Don't force EF to use a `List`.

Comment: @krillgar Alas, no luck with that either.

Comment: Is `package` `null`?

Comment: @CodeCaster No. As stated in the question it works fine when excluding the loading of the List<Fittings>.

Comment: Can you show the configuration for Fitting and any sub-classes?

Comment: @KGChristensen you are extending ProjectBase class and it has parameterized constructor. so Project class must pass parameter to base class ProjectBase constructor. your code should not compile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was of course in one of the classes which I didn't post in my original question. I had rather stupidly added an abstract field with only a `getter` in the abstract "`Fittings`" class. So, funnily enough the "cryptic error message" actually now makes complete sense.

```
public abstract string FittingsType { get; }
```

This field was introduced to help a legacy system and always returns a hard-coded value from the implementing base classes.

Many thanks for all the comments which lead me in the right direction.